# Sign xlsx file using c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, openxml, digital-signature

I am trying to sign my excel file (xlsx) with a digital signature.

The excel file is generated using the EPPlus library (uses office open xml).
Before the output of the xlsx file I have a byte array of the excel data.

Maybe I can do it with an X509 certificate and p7s detached signature?!

Does anyone of you have an idea how I can do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this thread https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2b888b80-1259-4c93-92fe-70784ed9cd0a/excel-document-digital-signature-with-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Thank you but that's not what I am searching for. I already checked this link before writing this question.